# How to plot frequency count of pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Year   Winner
4   1954  Germany
9   1974  Germany
13  1990  Germany
19  2014  Germany
5   1958   Brazil
6   1962   Brazil
8   1970   Brazil
14  1994   Brazil
16  2002   Brazil
```

How to plot the frequency count of column Winner, so that y axis has frequency and x-axis has name of country?

I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df.groupby('Winner').size().plot.hist()
df1['Winner'].value_counts().plot.hist()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are close, need [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html) because `value_counts` already count frequency:

```
df1['Winner'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image: g]

Also working:

```
df1.groupby('Winner').size().plot.bar()
```

Difference between solutions is output of `value_counts` will be in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element.

Comment: How would you get the relative frequency for the same plot?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to @jezrael's answer, you can also do:

```
df1['Winner'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Other one from @jezrael could be:

```
df1.groupby('Winner').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say this works with the latest version of plotly. Just need to add `,text_auto=True`.
Example:
`px.histogram(df, x="User Country",text_auto=True)`